# Securesocial with PlayFramework 2.3.x

Tags: maven, playframework, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I can't figure out how to integrate newest SecureSocial version with Play!
Because I can't find compiled artifacts anywhere.
In mvnrepository there are artifacts of versions 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 3.0-M1 and 3.0-M1-play-2.2.x.
As said here - http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html I added sonatype snapshots repo url to project.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```

But it didn't help! Because this repo contains only versions 2.10 and 2.11

Anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Ofn3NjadCc0)
, the correct **build.sbt** is:

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the master snapshot in Play 2.3.x, because of https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/issues/432.

Also, check out the activator templates:

- https://github.com/lunatech-labs/lunatech-securesocial-poc
- https://github.com/knockingspirit/paws#master
- https://github.com/raisercostin/securesocial-slick-bootstrap3-sample#master